# mysql_config not found with MySQL in Docker

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, docker, pip

I have MySQL 5.7 installed on Docker running perfectly and python 3.7 installed locally.

I tried to install the flask-mysqldb using the command

`pip install flask-mysqldb`

and I received an error

`OSError: mysql_config not found`

I never had to install a MySQL client connector in my machine and never had any problem to connect any system.

Is this related to my Docker config? 
How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Where did u execute the pip install command? Inside mysql container?

Comment: The python is running at my machine, and the MySQL in docker, then running pip on docker wont't work.

Comment: @hoefling I've checked all the links you proposed before asking. First of all, I'm using Mac. Second, I'm trying to make my local connector works with docker container.

Comment: @Light.G, Yes. I did. The error is the same

Answer (score 1):

Because the offical image of mysql:5.7 does not contain **libmysqlclient-dev**

just install this package and try again.

```
docker exec -it my_db bash
apt-get update
apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

If there issue with pip Like in testing I faced then run

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/

https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/9d1f62552b5dcf25d3102f14eb82b579ce9f4a26/5.7/Dockerfile

Comment: It works when I have python and Mysql installed on docker, I have MySQL on docker and python locally.

Comment: @Guerrato Docker image is bunch of files and directories, just like Linux itself. Of course, docker image includes other files to declare how docker daemon deals with files above. So in the image mysql:5.7, it does not include extra files(packages) but those mysql needs. In a word, it’s not best practice to install other packages in mysql:5.7. We’d better keep it as thin as we could.

Comment: So you can extend the mysql image and do modification for your self accordingly

Comment: Thank a lot all of you, but the problem wasn't with my docker.
I solved that following the
https://zehengl.github.io/2017/12/17/pip-install-mysqlclient-on-macos/